# web2py - getting posted json data through jquery

Tags: python, json, post, web2py

I'm new to web2py, trying to alter an existing application.

I have a JSON object in my JS, which I want to send to the server.

My JS is:

```
post_data = {ios: [{k:"v"}, 
                   {k: "v"}, 
                   {k: "v"}]};
$.post("/url", post_data, function(data) {}, "json"); // used with 'json' and without, same results
```

I want to access this data in my controller. so there, I tried to use `request.vars.ios` and `request.post_vars.ios`, getting a `None` ...

What am I doing wrong?

(note: the data is transmitted, and if i try to dump the `request.vars`, I get something like
`&lt;Storage {&#x27;ios[1][ranges_colors]&#x27;: &#x27;&#x27;, &#x27;ios[0] .... etc` which contains the data)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, on the client:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/url.json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    data: post_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:  function(data) {  alert('Data sent'); }
});
```

Then on the server:

```
data = gluon.contrib.simplejson.loads(request.body.read())
```

Comment: first: thanks. i will try, but can you direct me to why it's not working to start with..?